# Index row and index column of the minimum value matrix A in 2nd until 3rd row and 2nd column

Tags: matlab, minimum, indices

I have MATLAB code as below:

```
clear all;
clc;
A=[1 0 3;4 3 0;5 10 3]
[rows,columns]=find(A(:,2)==min(A(2:3,2)))
```

I want to find index row and index column of the minimum value matrix A in 2nd until 3rd row and 2nd column. Manually, we can find the minimum value is 3 with index row=2 and index column=2 (see below image)

[image]

But my problem if I use code above, the result is not same. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are inputting the column index so there is no need to find that again. The better approach would be to just do:

```
col_ind = 2;
[minimum, row_ind]  = min(A(2:3,col_ind)); 
row_ind = row_ind+1;      %1 is added since first row is skipped in above line
```

---

In your code,

- `A(2:3, 2)` has only 1 column. So `columns` will always be `1`.
- If `A(1,2)` is also the same as the minimum value, your code will return the row index of that first value.
- The fact that the first row and column are skipped in calculations is not incorporated in outputs.

Fixing above problems:

```
[rows,columns]=find(A(2:3,2)==min(A(2:3,2)));
rows=rows+1;     columns=columns+1;
```